# jQuery - blockUI() acts differently depending on browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, blockui

I'm trying to implement blockUI-pugin. In Firefox, blockUI works, but unblockUI does not. Firebug keeps telling me `unblockUI() is not a function`.

Then I tried to change browser (from FireFox to Chrome), just to see if it would make a difference - it did. Now when I run the code, the grey area doesn't appear anymore (this also happens in Safari) + unblockUI is still not working. Firebug shows that all my POST-variables is received and correct.

here is my AJAX-call:

```
function login() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#login').serializeArray(),
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my blockUI:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#message').load('login.html'), 
        css: {backgroundColor: '#00FF'}
    });
});
```

So, my two question are:

-Why isn't the grey shown in Chrome?

-Why doesn't unblockUI() work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How are you including/what order are you including the plugin?

Try adding your ajax call in the `$(document).ready()` so that way you are sure everything is loaded and ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#message').load('login.html'), 
        css: {backgroundColor: '#00FF'}
    });

function login() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#login').serializeArray(),
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.unblockUI;
        }
    });
};

});
```

Comment: I'm including it in my index.php and the order are:

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.blockUI.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js">
</script>

I tried the document-ready also, but it didn't work :/

Comment: what version of the blockui plugin are you using?

Comment: http://imgur.com/WwrX8hH - Here are the errors I'm getting. Removing the parentheses on unblockUI worked in the sense that Im not getting errors anymore - but still doesn't work. (Really enoying the fiddle is working - :P )

Comment: * jQuery blockUI plugin
 * Version 2.63.0-2013.07.08
 * @requires jQuery v1.7 or later

Comment: Would mind having a look at my lastest question? It's sort of a follow up to this question as I've solved most of this. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558947/unblockui-is-called-no-matter-what-ajax